# Postman: how to trigger a request by script

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I am using postman to test my service. Each test case contains 4 requests: A, B, C, D. Right now, I can test them slightly automatically by writing script that put the value from the previous request to the next one (A to B, B to C).

It's kind of fast but I still need to switch between tabs and press `Send` 4 times. Then I found out that I can use runner to help me run all of them in a single click.

It's sound great until I realize that I need to send the D request right after the C request sent **without** waiting for C to response, otherwise my test case will always fail.

Is there anyway to accomplish this? Does postman support a function to trigger another request?